# Issues with updating modules on Drupal 7

Tags: 7, updating, upgrading

I have a Drupal 7 website that I upgraded from Drupal 6 awhile ago. I am trying to upgrade some of the modules that have had updates since then, but I am having issues doing so. When I click the "Continue" button on the "ready to update" screen, I receive the following unformatted text on a blank white background:

> Installing updates
>
> Status message
>
> Operating in maintenance mode.Go online.

The url of the page is example.com/authorize.php?batch=1&op=start&id=4206

I checked the error logs in Drupal, and there are a few errors reports:

> Notice: Undefined variable: finished in _batch_process() (line 344 of
>   /home/mysite/public_html/includes/batch.inc).
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: old_set in _batch_process() (line 339 of
>   /home/mysite/public_html/includes/batch.inc).
>
> Notice: Undefinedvariable: old_set in _batch_process() (line 338 of
>   /home/mysite/public_html/includes/batch.inc).
>
> Notice: Undefined
>   variable: old_set in _batch_process() (line 337 of
>   /home/mysite/public_html/includes/batch.inc).
>
> Notice: Undefined index:
>   init_message in _batch_progress_page_js() (line 136 of
>   /home/mysite/public_html/includes/batch.inc).
>
> Notice: Undefined index:
>   error_message in _batch_progress_page_js() (line 135 of
>   /home/mysite/public_html/includes/batch.inc).
>
> Notice: Undefined index:
>   title in _batch_progress_page_js() (line 127 of
>   /home/mysite/public_html/includes/batch.inc).

Any ideas on what might be causing this and how I an fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I have encounted this in the past and usually you get a module that causes an issue with AJAX.

What I would suggest is to update modules manually (download from drupal.org, extract and upload then run update.php) or via drush one by one.

If you are doing multiple modules at once this can happen quite often.

Also make sure you have Overlay module disabled as for some odd reason this can cause the same error.

Your best bet is to update modules one by one to isolate which module is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks @pgrujic. I just finished updating the modules one-by-one, manually. I encountered no errors. Very strange... next time I will try disabling the overlay (although the overlay wasn't being used while I was attempting the auto-updates).

Comment: If you can use drush it will became your best friend to manage drupal sites. Glad I could help

Comment: I know this thread is a bit ancient, but I think I may have found the issue, at least on this one website. I upgraded the jquery update module to the latest version, and then chose "jquery" as the CDN. I can now run my updates! (for my own personal records, this was in regards to the rc website)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tangential, but I mention it to help anyone searching specifically for this error:

> Undefined variable: finished in _batch_process() (line 303 of /htdocs/includes/batch.inc)

...whilst using the *Editable Views* ([editableviews](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews)) module. The symptom for the user is saving the form and then it getting stuck on 'Initialising' on the batch screen, when you're just updating a single record, and manually refreshing the page will show the update has gone through.

In the view's Format > Settings page, if you scroll down, there's a checkbox right at the bottom labelled "Enable batch support" ("Use Batch API to save huge data.")

Just turn that off and the problem will go away.